# Разница между compile files и provided files c точки зрения разработчика библиотеки

Tags: android, android-library

Я создал простою библиотеку (`AAR`), которая при вызове функции взаимодействует с приложением через механизм бродкастов. И вот у меня возник вопрос: как правильно подключать её сторонним разработчикам через `compile files` и `provided files` и могу ли я на это как-то повлиять?

Насколько я понял из немногочисленной информации в интернете, если ее подключать через `compile files`, то она включается в APK, а если через `provided files`, то зависимость происходит на этапе компиляции. Я не совсем понимаю плюсы/минусы каждого подхода и как я могу на это повлиять в качестве разработчика?!

У меня был случай, когда я подключил стороннюю библиотеку через `compile files` вместо `provided files` и при вызове некоторых функций получал ошибку сигментации. Я не хочу, чтобы такая ситуация случилась с моей библиотекой и поэтому хочу подробнее разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: в описании к библиотеке вам нужно указать, как именно ее подключать, чтобы не возникло никаких проблем и соответственно самому тестировать с этим подключением, чтобы возможные проблемы решить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подключения зависимостей в Gradle есть несколько конфигураций:

1. `implementation` (`compile` до Gradle plugin 3.0)
   Самая часто используемая, добавляет при компиляции зависимость в classpath текущего модуля и добавляет в APK (для модулей с типом "приложение")
2. `api` (`compile` до Gradle plugin 3.0)
   Добавляет при компиляции зависимость в classpath текущего модуля и всех, кто использует его, также добавляет в APK (для модулей с типом "приложение"). Данную конфигурацию обычно используют в модулях библиотек для заявления транзитивных зависимостей.
3. `compileOnly` (`provided` до Gradle plugin 3.0)
   Добавляет при компиляции зависимость в classpath текущего модуля и НЕ добавляет в APK (для модулей с типом "приложение"). Например, вы используете библиотеку, которая опциональна и/или поставляется производителем устройства.
4. `runtimeOnly` (`apk` до Gradle plugin 3.0)
   Добавляет зависимость в APK, но НЕ добавляет при компиляции зависимость в classpath текущего модуля

Т.к. вы разработчик библиотеки, то вам следует уделить внимание использованию `implementation` и `api` для зависимостей вашей библиотеки.

Если библиотека используется в модуле приложения, то она подключается всегда через `implementation` (исключение - библиотеки, являющиеся частью Андроида на конкретном устройстве)

Comment: А как должна быть подключена библиотека на Kotlin в полностью Java-проекте, чтобы не нужно было добавлять зависимость на Kotlin compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"?

Comment: вы должны в библиотеке указать данную зависимость в конфигурации `api`, чтобы при сборке приложения она была доступна в classpath

Comment: Можно немного подробнее, у меня в библиотеке есть зависимость compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version", но похоже это не то?!

Comment: если у вас до сих пор используется Gradle Android Plugin версии ниже 3.0, то у вас верно. но вам стоит задуматься про миграцию: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: У меня используется 3.0.1

Comment: Этой зависимости в библиотеке не достаточно. Нужно такую же зависимость прописать в Java-проекте, иначе будет java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics . что не совсем корректно по отношению к пользователям библиотеки

Comment: взял случайную библиотеку на котлине ( https://github.com/hypeapps/NoiseView ) и добавил в java-проект без явного указания котлина в зависимостях. библиотека работает как и положено, в `releaseCompileClasspath` есть транзитивная зависимость на котлин

Comment: Через maven? Вроде как в maven-репе есть pom, в котором и прописана зависимость на рантайм. Я буду распространять свою либу как файл.

Comment: Если вы будете распространять свою либу как AAR-файл, то конечному пользователю придётся руками указывать все зависимости вашей библиотеки. PS: мы уже далеко ушли от исходного вопроса

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Вопрос закрыт.